# Why am I getting this error in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>>cast= ("1","2")
>>> cast.append("Gilliam")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    cast.append("Gilliam")
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The the code is written in **python 3**.

Comment: because you're looking for a list. `cast = ["1", "2"]`.

Comment: Also, tuples are immutable. So, if you are looking to update your structure, then use a list or a set. `[].append` or `{}.add`

Comment: what are tuples

Comment: also please write the complete code statement for this[ ].append or {}.add